# importing data from a json file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created some json data and saved it in a file named `quizdata.json` in xcode. I then selected the project target and clicked on Editor/ Add Build Phase/ Add Copy File Build Phase, selected the Products Directory and dropped the `quizdata.json` file in the space provided. I did not indicate a subpath because I read it wasn't needed and I don't know it :(

I then added the four lines at the bottom of this main function to import the file and serialize it into an object. However, when I run the code it's showing `null` when the json data should be output

```
Imported Questions: (null)
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Can you explain why it's null?

main
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

```
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Create the managed object context
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();

        // Custom code here...
        // Save the managed object context
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error while saving %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
            exit(1);
        }

        NSError* err = nil;
        NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"quizdata" ofType:@"json"];
        NSArray* Questions = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&err];
        NSLog(@"Imported Questions: %@", Questions);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample from quizdata.json

```
[{ "question" : "Do you like hairy fruit ?????????????????????????????", "answer1": "yes", "answer2": "no because my mouhth is like a large elastic band on tuesdays", "answer3": "maybe wonder never tried it but i should naturally", "answer4":"of course i do you beast of a man with a hairy nose", "correctAnswer": "yes", "unique": "1", "name": "fruitquiz", "quizId: 1"}
{ "question" : "Do you like fruit", "answer1": "yes", "answer2": "no", "answer3": "maybe", "answer4":"of course", "correctAnswer": "yes", "unique": "2", "name": "fruitquiz", "quizId: 1"}
...
```

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela I'm not sure if I understand your comment, but err is set to nil in the code that I copied from this blog tutorial for importing data http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated

Comment: yes you set it to nil initialy and call to NSJSOMSerialization JSONObjectWithData... will set it to NSError if there is an error so put this before you NSLog:
`if(err) NSLog("Error %@",[err description]);`

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela ok, thanks for that. There's a problem with the json data.... "The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted." (No value for key in object around character 375.) UserInfo=0x100515060 {NSDebugDescription=No value for key in object around character 375.}

Comment: have you solved issue?

Comment: 1) Check that "dataPath" is valid.  2) Break the "dataWithContentsOfFile" out on a separate line, assign to a temp, and make sure that's valid.  (The first thing to do in a situation like this is verify all your inputs so that you know precisely which step is failing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make Sure file is available in resource.

2) Check **NSData** length.
**(if data length is zero then it can be your json file issue, make sure you are validating json file)**

3) Save data as per your need in **NSArray** or **NSDictionary**.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"example" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

**(Note : You can check your file on http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ (for reference only))**

Comment: the json wasn't formatted correctly. The editor you linked to helped me.